# Changed domains unable to access service account in Sp13

Tags: sharepoint-server

I need some serious help here...

Background: Running two Hyper-V hosts one with SharePoint 2013 guest and the other with SQL 2012 guest.)

I've copied my working SQl 2012, and SharePoint 2013 environments from my production side over to my Development environment.  I've created all of the same account names in my Dev environment that I have in my prod environment.  I also went through services, IIS, and local computer permissions changing everything over from my prod (ssb1) to dev (ssbt) domain so now everything matches my prod set up except the domain names.

In Central admin when I try to go into Service Accounts I get the dreaded: (Sorry, something went wrong Some or all identity references could not be translated.)  using the sharepoint power shell I have gone and changed the farm admin account from the prod domain name to the dev domain name and deleted the old domain farm account, but I cannot change anything else because its still using the prod ssb1*** crap.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?  I cannot delete the old domain managed accounts because they are still linked the other components and I do not know how to change them any other way.

Any ideas?  Am I even making any sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the Service account and old accounts deleted from AD but still present in the Sharepoint Under Managed Account then old account become orphans.

Please run the below powershell to clean the orphan account first.
Try this one:

```
[Remove-SPManagedAccount][1] -Identity DOMAIN\ServiceAcct
```

if above did not work then use the below:

```
$OPAcc = Get-SPManagedAccount -Identity "domain\acctname"

$OPAcc.Delete()
```

Comment: That's my problem... it wont let me delete any of the old domain accounts because they have components tied to them and I don't know how to get them changed to the new domain accounts because it wont le me into the Service accounts page in Central admin.  Frustrating.

Comment: do you know the where it is tied, i mean application pool etc? you can change the account via pwoershell to new accounts, after that you have to run above powershell to delete them.

Comment: Well I was trying to stop all the services that were in use by the old accounts, but that is now a cluster f as I just hosed my connection.  I guess all I need to know are the powershell syntax commands to change over the accounts to the service accounts - thanks for all your help thus far!

Comment: ok I am back up (restored from a checkpoint).  I was trying to stop the services (in CA) that the accounts were using and one of those hosed up the page.  As I said above I just need to dissaccoate those accounts from the old domain (SSB1) to the new domain (SSBT).  All the accounts have the same names and permissions.

Comment: check this one to change the app pool identity https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/c3e2960c-56e3-4693-bcd2-dc15250bd2a9/changing-the-web-application-pool-identity-using-powershell

Comment: Services, App pool Identity, and group permissions I have already changed.. that was the first thing I did.  It's just the Service Accounts that I cannot get switch over because they are still holding on to the old SSB1 domain accounts.  I thought if I stopped the services in SharePoint I could remove them but that just hosed up Central Admin even though I kept that service running (I was able to change the farm admin just not the other service accounts.)  Sorry so long winded.

Comment: Where r they being used? What happen if you run the delete account ps.

Comment: When I run it on one of the old domain accounts I get this error: I had to remove several of them because it went over the character left: Exception calling "Delete" with "0" argument(s): "The account
SSB1\sp13farm_svcacc is still being used by these components:
SharePoint Server Search
Search Host Controller Service
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Application Pool: SharePoint - 80
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service
User Profile Synchronization Service
Secure Store Service
PowerPoint Conversion Service Application
Workflow Service Application
App Management Service"

Comment: also your first ps command did not work.  Id did not like the -SPManagedAccount syntax or something.